# Combining two regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a couple regular expressions, each of which works for stripping the beginning and ending parameters, but I'm looking for a way to combine them.

Capture beginning:

```
^[a][(]
```

Capture ending:

```
[\,]\d{1,3}\,[n][u][l][l][)]
```

I tried using the `&&` operator to combine them, but I am getting nothing.

This is an example of one of them on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/gJeQSi306A).

Comment: ... One regex with a capture group around the actual JSON. That said, are you sure a regex is the best way to do this, e.g., if there are newlines, just drop the first and last lines.

Comment: The JSONP response returns all in one line, as seen in the Rubular example.

Comment: Shouldn't removing "=?" on query url can return without that jsonp thing?

Comment: You're overusing character classes: `[n][u][l][l]` is the same as `null` — but note that parentheses need to be escaped with \, i.e., `[(]` is the same as `\(`.

Comment: Same question, I guess; if you know the callback format, you could probably just strip n chars at the beginning and end, e.g., first index of `{` and rindex of `}`.

Comment: Typically if API's support JSONP, they support raw JSON too. SO @YOU is probably right.  You probably don't need to do this...

Comment: ok, looks like it is Unofficial Google Dictionary API. some SO questions tell me others trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from removing `=?` on request url that I said on comment, you can use this if it is on one line.

```
^\w+\(|[^}]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match the start and end patterns and capture everything between:

```
/^a\((.*),\d{1,3},null\)/.match(s)[1]
```

Here how you can use it to strip:  (I edited down the huge string in your Rubular example)

```
irb> s = 'a({"query":"love",...},200,null)'
=> "a({\"query\":\"love\",...},200,null)"

irb> /^a\((.*),\d{1,3},null\)/.match(s)[1]
=> "{\"query\":\"love\",...}"

irb> puts /^a\((.*),\d{1,3},null\)/.match(s)[1]
{"query":"love",...}
```